# Int a, Что конкретно означает строка?

Tags: c++

```
int d[3] =  { a / 100 % 10, a / 10 % 10, a % 10};
```

Comment: Вам уже 2 раза ответили, попробую сформулировать еще раз.

Эта строка создает массив 32-бит целых из 3-х элементов, инициализированный тремя младшими цифрами числа `a`.

Comment: ... для случая положительного `a` (или нуля), и тремя младшими цифрами, снабжёнными знаком «минус», для отрицательного.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что в текущем виде он бесполезен кому бы то нибыло

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a%b - [остаток от деления](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC), так называемая операция mod

int d[3]={5,6,7};
Задаем массив из трех элементов: 5,6,7.

Допустим a=345, тогда

- a / 100 % 10 = 3
- a / 10 % 10 = 4
- a % 10 = 5

Т.е. мы разбили наше число на цифры, и записываем их в массив.

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего это массив, который содержит цифры, из которыз состоит число а. А в таком случае должно быть трехзначным. В общем случае он содержит последние три цифры в числе а. К примеру, для а = 458 массив будет таким: { 4, 5, 8 }. Для а = 4567 массив будет таким: { 5, 6, 7 }